# Using GCM service for mobile chat application

Tags: android

I want develop android chat app with the **`GCM`**. i had a series of questions : 
1) Whether messages are sent only on devices that have Google accounts or devices that do not have a Google account to get the message?
2) Any restrictions on sending messages or the number of requests per second or minute there?

** Please do not negative points and do not remove my question. I looked on the internet and did not receive a definitive answer. Here's why I raised my question.
Thanks your all my dear friens <3